# How to use paginate in DB raw complex queries

Tags: laravel

Please help me guys to use Paginate class of laravel with DB raw complex query...

Tried some tricks to get result with laravel paginate but because of query complexity it created problem for me

```
$data = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.name, c.active, c.image, c.created_at, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM categories WHERE c.id=parent_id) AS subcat_count, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post_ads WHERE c.id=cat_id) AS postad_count FROM categories AS c LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS subc ON c.id = subc.parent_id LEFT OUTER JOIN post_ads AS postadc ON c.id = postadc.cat_id WHERE c.parent_id=0 ORDER BY c.name ASC LIMIT 9"));
```

Comment: Can you post the dd of $data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Limit and Offset instead of paginate,
I was have same problem and solved it via using Limit and Offset.

```
$limit = 10;
$offset = 0; //change it dynamically

$data = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.name, c.active, c.image, c.created_at, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM categories WHERE c.id=parent_id) AS subcat_count, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post_ads WHERE c.id=cat_id) AS postad_count FROM categories AS c LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS subc ON c.id = subc.parent_id LEFT OUTER JOIN post_ads AS postadc ON c.id = postadc.cat_id WHERE c.parent_id=0 ORDER BY c.name ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset"));
```

Comment: Hi, Yes it was solved.
It was 3 year old question dude.

Answer (score 0):

you can paginate using length aware paginator, in you controller do like this,

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
...
class StudentAvailablitiesController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
       $collection = DB::select(DB::raw...)->get();
       $paginatedData = $collection->paginate(10);
   }

   public function paginate($perPage, $total = null, $page = null, $pageName = 'page')
   {
        $page = $page ?: LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);

        return new LengthAwarePaginator(
            $this->forPage($page, $perPage),
            $total ?: $this->count(),
            $perPage,
            $page,
            [
                'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
                'pageName' => $pageName,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working brother I already tried this kind of solution earlier because inside array -> object, object,.... it get data result so when using Paginate class it was showing Call to a member function paginate() on array

Comment: have you written own paginate method, you can convert array of objects to collection, and paginate collection try this once